How Can I use AutoIt to Browse the Registry for a Specific Program?
I am writing an installation script in AutoIt for a program, and I first need to determine if an older version of that same program already exists on my computer. I've written a function which takes the display name of the program I'm looking for and an integer which represents what property of that program I want (i.e. DisplayName, UninstallString, etc...). It's supposed to search the registry for the specified program and log the UninstallString, but it isn't able to see the program even though it's there.
The first version of my installation function was pretty bare bones. It's just storing the results of _UninstallEntry in a variable where I then log those results. After running my script, $VIS has a value of 0, which tells me that _UninstallEntry didn't find the desired program.
Here is my program installation function. It's always hitting the else statement, which shouldn't be happening.
Func InstallCapital()
    $VIS = _UninstallEntry('Capital2308_996-official', 1)
    If Not @error Then
        _WrtLog("VIS: " & $VIS)
    Else
        _WrtLog("Could not find Capital2308_996-official")
    EndIf
EndFunc

Here is the function I'm using to search the registry:
Func _UninstallEntry($displayname, $value = 0)
    Local $key_main = 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
    Local $i, $key_main, $key_result, $key_sub, $version, $size = StringLen($displayname)
    Switch $value
        Case 1
            $value = 'UninstallString'
        Case 2
            $value = 'QuietUninstallString'
        Case 3
            $value = 'DisplayVersion'
        Case Else
            $value = ''
    EndSwitch
    For $i = 1 To 1000
        $key_sub = RegEnumKey($key_main, $i)
        If @error Then ExitLoop
        If StringLeft(RegRead($key_main & '\' & $key_sub, 'DisplayName'), $size) = $displayname Then
            $data = RegRead($key_main & '\' & $key_sub, $value)
            If $value = '' Then Return 'Installed'
            If $data = '' Or @error Then ContinueLoop
            Return $data
        EndIf
    Next
    SetError(1)
    Return
EndFunc

